# Extracting Data from another Cell if the value is found in another column

Tags: excel

OK I have never posted on stack overflow so bear with me

I have An excel sheet with "asset numbers" and locations.

The actual objective I wont speak about but imagine this

From extracting Asset Numbers from another sheet, lets call it Sheet1. On sheet2, it contains those same asset numbers, along with others I don't need. Attached to each asset number is an address. Now my goal is to extract the address for all the asset numbers from sheet1 only.

In short, from the numbers on sheet1, I want to make a formula that will search for those asset numbers on sheet2, and return in another column the address of that asset number (from sheet one) on sheet1

[image: Example Picture]

Comment: did you try VLOOKUP,INDEX/MATCH, or XLOOKUP?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `VLOOKUP` for this. You just need to paste this formula in first sheet `B4` where you want to see the address and can drag it down. I have colored the cells where you drag is in green for easy reference.
Use formula `=VLOOKUP(A4,Sheet2!$A$4:$B$12,2,FALSE)`

Here is **Sheet1**

[image: Sheet1]

Here is **Sheet2**

[image: Sheet2]